# CRIU check shows warning in Raspberry-Pi-4(4gb version) on ubuntu server platform

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, arm64

```
Warn  (criu/cr-check.c:680): Dirty tracking is OFF. Memory snapshot will not work.
Warn  (criu/cr-check.c:1061): Do not have API to map vDSO - will use mremap() to restore vDSO
Warn  (criu/cr-check.c:1029): CRIU built without CONFIG_COMPAT - can't C/R ia32
Looks good but some kernel features are missing
which, depending on your process tree, may cause
dump or restore failure.
```

Comment: Yes - there is a warning. Yes - there is an explanation of the warning. But what is the question?

Comment: i need to recompile the criu to make it work in my raspberry pi.
I'm not sure how to solve it exactly

Comment: Put a little more effort into your question if you want people to spend time on it. First explain the problem you are trying to solve. Then show the steps you have taken yourself. Which commands used etc. You cannot expect people to give a quality answer without anything to work with.

Comment: Ok, i'm trying to recompile the kernel of my raspberry pi after installing CRIU and all its dependencies. I've installed CRIU in order to perform live LXC container migration from one raspberry pi to another.
After booting my RPi with ubuntu server, which is preloaded with lxc, i gave the following commands:

Comment: i gave the following commands to install criu & its dependencies:
$apt install libprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-c-dev protobuf-c-compiler protobuf-compiler python-protobuf pkg-config python-ipaddress libbsd-dev iproute2 libcap-dev libnl-3-dev libnet-dev libaio-dev python3-future make gcc build-essential git asciidoc build-essentials
$git clone https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu
$cd criu
$make
$make install
$criu check --all

Comment: The output i got for <  $criu check --all >  command is in my post.

Comment: i tried the recompiling commands from the website: https://criu.org/ARM_crosscompile.
The commands are  as follows:
https://criu.org/ARM_crosscompile

Comment: The output was as follows:
make: * No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Comment: This is my kernel version: 5.3.0-1014-raspi2 And my build machine details are as follows: DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10 DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.10" NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.10" VERSION_ID="19.10" HOME_URL="ubuntu.com" SUPPORT_URL="help.ubuntu.com" BUG_REPORT_URL="bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" VERSION_CODENAME=eoan UBUNTU_CODENAME=eoan